# Why does user defined signal handler execute again and again when the signal() call resets to SIG_DFL?

Tags: c, signals, posix

Apparently, `signal()` resets to SIG_DFL (default) which is why another another signal of the same type arriving immediately after the first causes default behaviour to occur. My question is: why does this thing happen only if the second signal occurs immediately? Shouldn't it happen regardless of whether the second signal is immediate or not considering that the signal has been reset? I am mighty confused. Please clarify.

Comment: The behaviour of `signal()` varies between systems — widely.  The C standard specifies a minimalist version of [`signal()`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.14.1.1); POSIX specifies [`signal()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/signal.html) too.  But both specifications allow for a wide range of behaviours to retain compatibility with legacy systems.  If you want control, use POSIX [`sigaction()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html).

Answer (score 1):

The specification of [§7.14.1.1 The `signal` function](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.14.1.1) in the C standard is carefully worded to allow quite a variety of behaviours, mainly because when the standard was created, existing implementations of `signal()` provided a wide variety of behaviours.
The POSIX specification for [`signal()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/signal.html) follows the C standard, but places fewer restrictions on the actions in the signal handler.

The C standard says:

> ```
>      #include <signal.h>
>     void (*signal(int sig, void (*func)(int)))(int);
> ```
>
> Description
>
> 2 The `signal` function chooses one of three ways in which receipt of the signal number sig is to be subsequently handled. If the value of `func` is `SIG_DFL`, default handling for that signal will occur. If the value of `func` is `SIG_IGN`, the signal will be ignored. Otherwise, `func` shall point to a function to be called when that signal occurs. An invocation of such a function because of a signal, or (recursively) of any further functions called by that invocation (other than functions in the standard library),<sup>251)</sup> is called a signal handler.
>
> 3 When a signal occurs and `func` points to a function, it is implementation-defined whether the equivalent of `signal(sig, SIG_DFL);` is executed or the implementation prevents some implementation-defined set of signals (at least including `sig`) from occurring until the current signal handling has completed; in the case of `SIGILL`, the implementation may alternatively define that no action is taken. Then the equivalent of `(*func)(sig);` is executed. If and when the function returns, if the value of sig is `SIGFPE`, `SIGILL`, `SIGSEGV`, or any other implementation-defined value corresponding to a computational exception, the behavior is undefined; otherwise the program will resume execution at the point it was interrupted.
>
> 4 If the signal occurs as the result of calling the `abort` or `raise` function, the signal handler shall not call the `raise` function.
>
> 5 If the signal occurs other than as the result of calling the `abort` or `raise` function, the behavior is undefined if the signal handler refers to any object with static or thread storage duration that is not a lock-free atomic object other than by assigning a value to an object declared as `volatile sig_atomic_t`, or the signal handler calls any function in the standard library other than the `abort` function, the `_Exit` function, the `quick_exit` function, or the `signal` function with the first argument equal to the signal number corresponding to the signal that caused the invocation of the handler. Furthermore, if such a call to the `signal` function results in a `SIG_ERR` return, the value of `errno` is indeterminate.<sup>252)</sup>
>
> 6 At program startup, the equivalent of
>
> ```
>     signal(sig, SIG_IGN);
> ```
>
> may be executed for some signals selected in an implementation-defined manner; the equivalent of
>
> ```
>     signal(sig, SIG_DFL);
> ```
>
> is executed for all other signals defined by the implementation.
>
> 7 Use of this function in a multi-threaded program results in undefined behavior. The implementation shall behave as if no library function calls the `signal` function.

The classic structure for a signal handler assumed that the system would reset the signal handling to `SIG_DFL` and carefully restored the signal handler as the first action in the handler:

```
static void handler(int signum)
{
    signal(signum, handler);
    // Other actions
}
```

However, there is a small window of time during which the signal handling is the default, so if a second signal arrives during that (short) interval, the program may be stopped.  That's why "another another signal of the same type arriving immediately after the first causes default behaviour to occur".  And because the handler is written as shown, there is only a small interval during which the default signal handling is in effect.  If the handler does not reset the signal handling, then it doesn't matter when the second signal arrives.

If you want control over the signal handling, use POSIX
[`sigaction()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html).  It has options to support all the behaviours of `signal()` and provides much better control.  By default, it does not reset the signal handling to `SIG_DFL`; it avoids that window of vulnerability.